How to launch Chrome or Chromium as guest in Playwright
I'm trying to execute my tests (chrome/chromium) in guest mode instead of incognito.
I have this code that let me execute with an existing user-profile, but not as guest:
const userDataDir = "C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
const browser = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(
  userDataDir,
  {channel: "chrome"}
);

Note that data-dir is a directory that includes all chrome signed-in users data with no clear separation between then

Did you try adding args: ["--guest"] to the options object? Do you want the userDaraDir to be there? I guess I'm not really clear what the context/underlying goal is here.

No I don't need userDataDir, I just want to run with guest profile.

Thanks to ggorlen comment, I've managed to find a solution (no actual mention in the docs)
the solution is using launchPersistentContext with args: ["--guest"] set in the launchOptions.
code example:
test("launch chromium as guest", async ({}, testInfo) => {
  if (testInfo.project.name !== "chromium") test.skip();

  const browser = await chromium.launchPersistentContext("", {
    args: ["--guest"],
  });

  // launchPersistentContext already creates a page for you,
  // so `const page = await browser.newPage();` is not needed here,
  // instead get the page from browser.pages()
  let page = browser.pages().at(0) as Page;
  if (!page) page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");
});

